# Salesforce Chat Availablity API not working

Tags: apex, rest-api, liveagent, chat, pre-chat-api

I am new to Salesforce chat API. I had a requirement to check the chat button availability status. upon research I found below API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Availability.htm

I am getting 200 response(see screenshot) but I am not getting availability status in the response body for button Ids. Any help would be appreciated.[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: If agent is available then isAvailable : true and if the agent is not available, then we do not get isAvailable parameter itself in the response body.,Can you make sure the agent is available and try the REST call?

Answer (score 0):

If the agent is available then `isAvailable : true` parameter is returned in the response body and if the agent is not available, then we do not get isAvailable parameter itself in the response body. Please make sure the agent is available and try the REST call.